# Working (unofficial) pen and paper rpg adaptation of Mass Effect?

Tags: game-recommendation

Just *out of curiosity*: **Do you know of a working pen and paper adaptation of Bioware's Mass Effect franchise?** I think there's no such official publication (though there might be one in the works, who knows), but there may be a good unofficial version.

Comment: I haven't played Mass Effect. What aspects of that game are you looking for in a PnP game?

Comment: The world itself. I haven't been looking for a game with a "similar" feel, I've been curious whether there was an usable adaptation. (I've just accepted @mxyzplk's answer, for it pointed me to such a game, which satisfied my curiosity. :))

Comment: I just suggested Gurps as a system that will support everything that exists in mass effect, but isn't directly written for it.

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably most complete are [these two d6-based Mass Effect RPGs](http://www.bozark.com/mass/x/downloads.html). And there's a [Cortex stab at one here](http://cortexsystemrpg.org/index.php?topic=3913.0) (you have to register to see and download the files attached to the thread). Then there's Dagda who has been [noodling away on a Mass Effect 2 RPG on his blog](http://dagda-mor.blogspot.com/search/label/Mass%20Effect), I don't think it's downloadable but he says he's running it at cons.  There's about a dozen less baked mods out there too.

Update - Wesley Schneider of Paizo has been running Mass Effect in Pathfinder and he has just published all his notes and stuff as [Project Lobotomy](http://erraticepisodes.blogspot.com/2013/01/episode-two-project-lobotomy-download.html).

Comment: Nicely done versions there, I'm now tempted to run it!

Answer (score 6):

There are few suggestions on converting Mass Effect into systems like Traveler, Fate or Savage World.

Otherwise there are no official Mass Effect RPGs.

I just ran across [Mass Effect d6:  The Unofficial RPG](http://www.bozark.com/mass/x/downloads.html).

I myself am currently working on a Mass Effect Campaign Guide and Players Guide for Dungeons and Dragons 4th Edition.  The sneak peaks are available at [Mass Effect RPG](http://masseffectrpge.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Definitely interested to see what you do class-wise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a Mass-Effect RPG currently in a d10 format. Though its not as common as a format as d20, I feel there is a better balancing between tech, biotics and normal combat.

Here's our Facebook page: [Mass Effect RPG](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mass-Effect-RPG/310506462390604)

Comment: Could you expand this a bit more? Tell us what stage of development you're in? Perhaps give us an example of the core mechanics and how they support the narrative of Mass Effect?